# Adding a download button to shiny, which prints the output of the server function

Tags: r, download, shiny

Im having trouble adding a download button to download my plots, getting the error message: "eading objects from shinyoutput object not allowed."

```
´  x <- output$Plot
  output$down <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){
      paste("AAA", input$var3, sep = ".")
    },
    content = function(file){
      if(input$var3 == "png")
      png(file)
      else
        pdf(file)
      plot(x)
      dev.off
    }
  )´
```

The Problem is i cannot simply add plot(x(), y()) because in my server i do calculate around 7 different plots, each having a different dataset, and being "glued" together with else if.

```
`ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("Select2","Partei:", choices = c("AFD", "CDU", "DieLinke", "FDP", "Gruene", "Piraten", "SPD", "total")),
      selectInput("Select1", "Function:", choices = c("Absolute Worthaufigkeiten", "Relative Worthaufigkeiten",
                                                      "Wordclouds", "Term frequencies", "Sentiment Analysis 1", "Importance")),
      radioButtons(inputId = "var3", label = "Select file type", choices = list("png", "pdf"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
    plotOutput("Plot"),
    downloadButton(outputId = "down", label = "Download the Plot")
  )))`


`server <- function(input, output) {output$Plot <- renderPlot({
if(input$Select1 == "Absolute Worthaufigkeiten"){
  if(input$Select2 == "AFD"){
    AAA %>%
      filter(AFD > 2) %>%
      ggplot(aes(word, AFD, Jahr)) +
      geom_col(colour = "white", fill = "red2")
  }
  else{
    if(input$Select2 == "CDU"){
      AAA %>%
        filter(CDU > 80) %>%
        ggplot(aes(word, CDU)) +
        geom_col(colour = "red3", fill = "red3") 
        else {

            }
           else {
          if(input$Select1 == "Importance"){
            if(input$Select2 == "AFD"){
              print("NA")
            else{
              if(input$Select2 == "CDU"){

                book_words_CDU <- tidy_CDU_total %>%
                  count(book, word, sort = TRUE) %>%
                  ungroup()

                total_words_CDU<- book_words_CDU %>%
                  group_by(book) %>% 
                  summarize(total = sum(n))

                book_words_CDU <- left_join(book_words_CDU, total_words_CDU)

                book_words_CDU <- book_words_CDU %>%
                  bind_tf_idf(word, book, n) }})}
```

Is there any way to have shiny print out the output?

Comment: Do You create Your plot using a function?

Comment: I do create the plots using ggplot, here is an example:

else{
      if(input$Select1 == "Wordclouds"){
        if(input$Select2 == "AFD"){
          tidy_AFD_2013 %>%
            count(word) %>%
            with(wordcloud(word, n, max.words = 100))

Thats not a ggplot one since it would be too long for the comment, i cant add the whole code aswell since its almost 1500 rows long

Comment: You should post reproducible example which does not need to be same as Your original code, just simplified. And definatelly this code should not be in the comment! You should move it to the question part

Comment: if(input$Select1 == "Importance"

 if(input$Select2 == "SPD"){gplot(frequency_SPD, aes(x = proportion, y = `2013`, color = abs(`2013` - proportion))) + geom_abline()

else{
                if(input$Select2 == "CDU"){gplot(frequency_CDU, aes(x = proportion, y = `2013`, color = abs(`2013` - proportion))) + geom_abline()}

else{
if(input$Select1 == "Absolute Worthäufigkeit"){
if(input$Select2 == "CDU") {AAA %>%
            filter(CDU > 80) %>%
            ggplot(aes(word, CDU)) +
            geom_col(colour = "red3", fill = "red3")
else{if(inpu$Select2 == "SPD") ...... And so on

Comment: how do You call this object?

Comment: I do call i output$Plot which is part of the server function, i added a small example of my code, i hope i didnt add any syntax errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As You didnt post reproducible example, i assume that You do not have any problems with plotting and you can see the plot in Your app, please try this:

1. Place Your whole code inside of the function, like:

   ```
   testplot <- function() {
     if (input$Select1 == "Absolute Worthaufigkeiten") {
       if (input$Select2 == "AFD") {
         AAA %>%
           filter(AFD > 2) %>%
           ggplot(aes(word, AFD, Jahr)) +
           geom_col(colour = "white", fill = "red2")
       }
       else{
         if (input$Select2 == "CDU") {
           AAA %>% ...
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. Render the function `testplot()`:

   ```
   output$Plot <- renderPlot({testplot()})
   ```
3. Download the plot using `downloadHandler()`:

   ```
   output$down <- downloadHandler(
     filename = function() {
       paste("AAA", input$var3, sep = ".")
     },
     content = function(file) {
       if (input$var3 == "pdf") {
         pdf(file, width = 30, height = 20)
       }
       else{
         png(file, width = 1200, height = 800, units = "px", pointsize = 12, bg = "white", res = NA)
       }
       print(testplot())
       dev.off()
     }
   )
   ```

Comment: This works very vell, it only seems to not paste the desired name before downloading. If i enter .png/.pdf  manually behind the name it works as desired. Thank you a lot for this simple solution.